# TypeScript says this expression is not callable. Type 'currentValueType' has no call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

For some reasons TypeScript says, that i have such a mistake.

[image]

Before that i tried to call simple function from App component, but React says it is not a function. Everything seems to be very easy, but for some reasons a lot of mistakes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Typescript is saying is true; as per your code, getCurrentValue is not a method but a variable that satisfies the currentValueType interface, and therefore it is not callable.

As per your code, you should access it in the following manner:

```
getCurrentValue.getCurrentValue()
```

Also, inside your App component, you want to pass an object that satisfies your currentValueType interface.
Your code then translates in:

```
<ReadingTitlePage getCurrentValue={{getCurrentValue}} />
```

Note: I added brackets to tell JSX I am passing an object containing the getCurrentValue (satisfies the interface) and not the method itself.

You probably want to learn more about interfaces:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

and about passing properties to components: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I just thought I had already put my function inside props and I did not need to write it twice like getCurrentValue.getCurrentValue().  Shame on me.

Comment: Hi @Fyodor76 I'm so glad you did solve your problem :) If my answer was correct, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer so it will help other people with the same issue as yours? Thanks!